# How to detect a minimum android version for Flutter project?

Tags: android, flutter

Let's say there is a project which compiles and it's actualy production ready. How to detect which a minimum android version is suitable for it?

Comment: I don't think there is some way of doing it automatically. But you can start with API 16, try to build the generated APK, and if there's some error (like minSdkVersion shouldn't be lower than xxx), you can increase the `compileSdkVersion`.

Comment: @animusmind I am not sure if he is asking that question.

Comment: Thansk @iDecode, you're correct.

Comment: @rozerro there is nothing as such even in the native Android Development. you have to define it manually and write the code using the available APIs from the SDK installed.